# Create an Image In Pillow with Numpy Matrix of Colors

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create some "abstract" images from some data. I have a numpy matrix with rows of RGB values:

```
[[158.3843526 173.15808009 99.35181516], [133.06784447 119.41070161 95.89276837], [150.15054271 150.09915693 129.7414471], [170.31807292 153.84166341 126.4784592]]
```

Currently I import the array and calculate how many values there are using: `colors.shape[0]`

I then divide the number of values in 1920 (I am trying to create 1920x1080 images) using: `segment = int((1920/colors.shape[0]))`

To create the actual image I am using Pillow and the following code: `img = Image.new('RGB', (segment, 1080), color=(int(colors.item((0, 0))), int(colors.item((0, 1))), int(colors.item((0, 2)))))`

I am then saving this image using: `img.save('pil_color.png')`

This code works as expected creating an image with the first RGB value, I want to change my code to fill the image with all RGB values in Matrix. How can I change the pillow code to create a striped even image with all values in matrix?

Here is the complete code:

```
segment = int((1920/colors.shape[0]))
img = Image.new('RGB', (segment, 1080), color=(int(colors.item((3, 0))), int(colors.item((3, 1))), int(colors.item((3, 2)))))
img.save('image.png')
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code I have now which generates strips from the matrix but I can't combine them properly yet, all i get is a black 1920x1080 image.

```
segment = int((1920/colors.shape[0]))
for i in range(colors.shape[0]):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (segment, 1080), color=(int(colors.item((i, 0))), int(colors.item((i, 1))), int(colors.item((i, 2)))))
    img.save(old + "/strips/" + 'image' + str(i) + '.png')

images = []
for filename in glob.glob(old + '/strips/*.png'):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    images.append(im)

widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
    new_im.paste(im, (x_offset, 0))
    x_offset += im.size[0]

new_im.save(old + "/" + str(query) + str(num) + '.jpg')
```

Comment: What's a *"striped even image"* please? What are the dimensions of your input array and the dimensions of your expected output image please?

Comment: By input array is the first code block with each row corresponding to a RGB value, the output image should be 1920x1080 with x number of even spaced columns one for each row in the matrix. @MarkSetchell

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated the post with my further code

Comment: Sorry, I still have no concept of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I managed to figure it out, here's what it made: https://imgur.com/a/UTzjz3S

Comment: Should make nice wallpaper :-)

Comment: Yeah, I can put in any word and it generates one.